# Need help in understanding this error message that I'm getting

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me understand what is this error that I'm getting:

[image]

lblTabCounter is a label coded in the aspx page while the lblc[index] is a collection of label created at runtime during page load.

Declaration outside of page load:

```
Label[] lblc = new Label[10];
```

Inside Page Load Event:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    lblc[i] = new Label() { Text = (i + 1).ToString() };
                    this.Controls.Add(lblc[i]);
                }
```

Inside another event called NodeChanged:

```
int TabCount = Convert.ToInt32(lblTabCounter.Text.ToString());
                int TabIndex = Convert.ToInt32(lblTabCounterIndex.Text.ToString());
                if(TabCount <= 10)
                {
                    divcont.Visible = true;
                    string tabName = getURLName(uRL);

                    MenuItem myItem = new MenuItem(tabName, TabIndex.ToString());
                    Menu1.Items.AddAt(TabIndex, myItem);
                    //f1.Attributes["src"] = url;
                    f1.Attributes.Add("src", lblURL.Text.ToString());
                    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = TabIndex;
                    lblc[TabCount].Text = lblTabCounter.Text;
                    lblc[TabCount + 1].Text = lblURL.Text;
                    TabCount++;
                    TabIndex++;
                    lblTabCounter.Text = TabCount.ToString();
                    lblTabCounterIndex.Text = TabIndex.ToString();
                    tvPermissions.ExpandAll();
                    //tvPermissions.CollapseAll();
                    int i = ctr;
                }
```

Note: This are all inside site.master.

Comment: I think we would be able to help more if you post the method. This is a very common error, and many things can cause it. My guess, just looking at the code is that `lblc[TabCount]` is not initialized (`new Label`)

Comment: Alright I will update my post.

Comment: @passionateCoder Please check my post I alreay updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your web page is refreshing and losing the state of the labels.

```
    Label[] lblc = new Label[10];
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            lblc[i] = new Label();
            this.Controls.Add(lblc[i]);
            if (Session["lblc" + i.ToString()] == null)
                Session["lblc" + i.ToString()] = lblc[i].Text = (i + 1).ToString();
            else
                lblc[i].Text = (string)Session["lblc" + i.ToString()];
        }
```

Then when you want to set a label you use the following (when the page is not being refreshed by the event)

```
        lblc[4].Text = "cool";
        Session["lblc4"] = "cool";
```

However because your click event is refreshing the page it loses contact with the lblc so you only set the Session so upon refresh you will see your new Label. (when the page is being refreshed by the event)

```
        Session["lblc4"] = "cool";
```

The page is in the process of refreshing as a result of your particular event so the label disappears but the session state remains so when you set the session upon refresh the code grabs the session instead of setting it to the default number.
Rather than change the text of the label when it refreshes you are actually generating the new label with the session string you set.

Also make sure you have `<sessionState mode="InProc" />` in your Web.config file under `<system.web>`
Please read more on Session States here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87069683(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Hey you're back this is related to your code exactly the one that you provided now.

Comment: Can we continue this through chat? I have a lot of questions and I hope you could help me.

Comment: This code that you provided I put the for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
     lblc[i] = new Label() { Text = (i + 1).ToString() };
 } in the page load while I declare Label[] lblc = new Label[10]; outside of it.

Comment: Try replacing TabCount with the number 0 and see if it gives you an error, then replace TabCount with the number 9 and see if it is giving you an error.

Comment: Sure I can chat. I have never used the chat function before I just joined the c# chat room.

Comment: However let me try changing the index to 0 or 1.

Comment: Ok let me try that as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31365/discussion-between-codecamper-and-chris-n-p)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible issues with that line of code:

- `lblc[TabCount]` is null.
- `lblTabCount` is null.

Since you are paused in the debugger, you can see which of those is the case, then look around in the rest of the code to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the path of the lblc[index] array to determine if the element offset is within range as well as it being created properly and not ending up there as a null (whether the null being the object lblc[index] or the text property) being referenced.